# Why doesn't my GXT form look like the sample?

Tags: java, layout, gxt

I've copied all the code from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/TwocolumnformExtGWT.htm) but instead of looking like the sample it looks like the below screenshot. Obviously I'm missing something fundamental but being completely green in Java, GXT, and web development I'm unsure where to start. Any pointers gratefully received. [image: GXT Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using GXT 2 or 3?
Check to ensure the gxt-all.css file is loading correctly. I'm assuming you copied the gxt resources in to your project, and you're referencing their CSS file in your host/entry point page.

Comment: Bingo! You hit the problem perfectly. Somebody else had (partially) set up the project I'm working on. Eventually I found the problem by finding a 'getting started' guide and working backwards.

Answer (score -1):

for a gxt development i sugest to use eclipse. i dont know which editor you are using. did you delete some image.
[Ext Gwt 2.0: Beginner's Guide](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=JnbPZ2Jy63IC&pg=PT402&dq=gxt%20pdf&hl=en&sa=X&ei=t4HxT57mEZDJrQeS1uy9DQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=gxt%20pdf&f=false) the best bookk for beginers please follow each steps. it is really easy to learn. cheerssssss